# The form of navigation. How can I change the color of the line under the "navigation item"?

Tags: ms-access

The form of navigation. How can I change the color of the line under the "navigation item"?
[image: see screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the tab block and change the Gridline Color property.
[image]